Backtrader Multiple Stocks with different end datetime problem
I am using Backtrader in order to analysis multiple stocks until today (2024-11-22). I have a problem with Deslisted stocks that they have end datetime different (for example: ABMD finished at 2022-12-21, and today is 2024-11-22).
The behaviour of backtarder is to use the last days line (2022-12-21), with open and close prices of that day until 2024-11-22. Is there any filter or something to solve these and complete with zero or NaN? Any Idea?
The last line of the CSV data of ABMD stock is:

Date:   2022-12-21,
Open:   380.78, (this value is used to complete all the data until 2024-11-22)
High:   381.28,
Low:    380.51,
Close:  381.02,  (this value is used to complete all the data until 2024-11-22)
Volume: 20612256

In my example, I have the following log:

2023-04-06, Pre Buy - Stock: Delisted_ABMD - Price: 381.02 (Close Price)
2023-04-10, Buy Executed - Stock: Delisted_ABMD - Price: 380.78 (Next day Open Price)

Looking in backtrader guide or stackoverflow, but not find anything!
I am expecting backtrader complete the empty data until 2024-11-22 with zero o NaN values.
Thanks for all :)

would be easier to help you if you could add a simple example input and output you're expecting
